# Cannot Get grid style map to be drawn in JFrame

Tags: java

I am working on a simple game and do not have much JFrame background. How should i go about drawing a grid based map (20x20) with dynamic changes to the tiles (ie set pictures in them)?

Comment: maybe look at `jtable` and `jtablerenderer`, or write a custom paint method.

Comment: i have tried pretty much everything i could find, i made a grid layout and tried to make pictures in each space via jlabel, ive tried painting it , but nothing works